# SpringFramework Upgrade is causing MongoDB driver to throw CodecConfigurationException

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, codec, spring-data-commons, bsondocument

I'm currently in the process of upgrading several libraries in my project:

- **org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-legacy:4.6.1** to **4.8.2**
- **org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.6.1** to **4.8.2**
- **org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:4.6.1** to **4.8.2**
- **org.mongodb:bson:4.6.1** to **4.8.2**
- **org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.7.7** to **3.0.6**
- **org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:3.4.7** to **4.0.6**
- **org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.27** to **6.0.9**
- **org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.27** to **6.0.9**
- **org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.27** to **6.0.9**
- **org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.27** to **6.0.9**
- **org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.27** to **6.0.9**
- **org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.27** to **6.0.9**
- **org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.3.27** to **6.0.9**
- **org.springframework:spring-test:5.3.27** to **6.0.9**
- **org.springframework:spring-tx:5.3.27** to **6.0.9**
- **org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.27** to **6.0.9**

I've attempted this upgrade with both MongoDB server versions 5.0 and 6.0, as the MongoDB driver release page suggests using MongoDB server version 6.0 for Driver version 4.8. However, I'm still encountering issues.

Our use case involves the following scenario:

```java
class Field<T> {
  private T value;
}

class Example1 {
  Field<ClassMapping_T_1> store;
}

// One of the classes we use in Field<T>
class ClassMapping_T_1 {
  Config config; // This is an interface
}

// One of the classes we use in Field<T>
class ClassMapping_T_2 {
  String selector;
  String origin;
}

interface Config {
  // Few methods that will be overridden by several other classes
}

class ClassImplementing_Config_1 implements Config {
  String uid; 
  Field<List<String>> files;  // This is what is causing the exception
}
```

We have a generics class `Field<T>`, where `T` can map to over 100 other classes, and these classes can internally also have `Field<T>`.

In the above scenario, we've observed that `spring-data-commons` is mapping `Field<List<String>>` to `Field<ClassMapping_T_2>` and creating a MongoDB BSON Document object that contains `Field<ClassMapping_T_2>` instead of `Field<List<String>>`. When this Document reaches the MongoDB driver, it complains that a Codec is not found for `Field<ClassMapping_T_2`, resulting in a CodecConfigurationException.

Upon further debugging, we noticed that the issue arises in the `spring-data-commons` library's `AbstractMappingContext` class. Before the upgrade, the `persistentEntities` map in `AbstractMappingContext` had over 2500 entries, whereas after the upgrade, it had roughly 1900 entries.

Before the library upgrade, we observed that `AbstractMappingContext` had the mapping for `Field<List<String>>`. After the upgrade, however, it didn't have any mappings for `Field<List<String>>`, but it did have a mapping for `Field<ClassMapping_T_2>`. Consequently, `spring-data-commons` mapped `Field<List<String>>` to the entity of `Field<ClassMapping_T_2>`, creating a wrongly wired MongoDB BSON Document object. When this document is given to the MongoDB driver, it complains that there is no Codec found for `ClassMapping_T_2`, resulting in a CodecConfigurationException.

`AbstractMappingContext` creates all the mapping contexts through Guice. We tried upgrading `org.springframework.guice:spring-guice`, which is the bridge from `com.google.inject:guice`, but had no luck with it.

Could any Spring Framework subject matter experts or contributors kindly assist with this issue?